# Analytics API: How to define a segment by using event category AND event action

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

**Question**

Is is possible to create a segment (not a filter) which contains only Session1 and not Session2.

**Situation**

```
## Event Defintion
          Category  Action
Event A   CatX      ActX
Event B   CatX      ActY
Event C   CatY      ActX

## accured sessions
Session1: Event A is fired
Session2: Event B is fired AND Event C is fired
```

**Attemps**

sessions::condition::ga:eventCategory==CatX;ga:eventAction==ActX
Would return both of the session. For session1 event A would fulfill both conditions. In Session2 Event B would fulfill the first condition and Event C would fulfill the second.

**Idea**

sessions::condition::(ga:eventCategory==CatX;ga:eventAction==ActX)
The () shall express, that one event has to match both of the conditions. I have never seen an example working with parantethis.
Is this somehow possibel? If so could you share an example?

Thanks a lot for the support!

Comment: are you sure this is related to the API?  try testing here https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Comment: Hey DalmTo, the link you posted is an implementation of the same api I'm using. The documention can also be found here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/

Answer (score 2):

try using [Sequence Conditions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments#sequence-conditions) for your task.

SESSION1:

```
sessions::sequence::ga:eventCategory==X;ga:eventAction==X
```

SESSION2:

```
sessions::sequence::ga:eventCategory==X;ga:eventAction==Y;->>ga:eventCategory==Y;ga:eventAction==X
```

plus

```
sessions::sequence::ga:eventCategory==Y;ga:eventAction==X;->>ga:eventCategory==X;ga:eventAction==Y
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Max. However, if neither -> nor ->> it does not indicate it is in the same hit according to my understanding. So sessions::sequence::ga:eventCategory==X;ga:eventAction==Y;->>ga:eventCategory=@Y;ga:eventAction=@X
 leads to session has to contain category==X and eventAction=@Y and there has to be the sequence action==y and category=@x. Do you share this view?

Comment: Hi @SteveEastwood, I agree that it isn't declared clearly in the documentation so I'll ask from support and tell you. P.S. changed `=@` to `==` in segments.

Comment: The approach by using sequences is working. Thank you for that. It doesn't exactly solve the issue I had, so I keep the issue unsolved.

Comment: @SteveEastwood GA confirmed that every step of a sequence represents a single hit. And I think the easiest way to get this segment is to set a custom dimension for these kind of sessions while collecting data (from a cookie for example).